# Files Not Downloading Properly In Django/Nginx

Tags: python, django, nginx

I want users to be able to download file from my django web app. I wrote the below codes, but when I download a file, the file will turn into an error file. It won't open and the total size of the file would be 0 bytes.

Models:

```
class Emov(models.Model):
    User=models.ForeignKey(User)
    mov_file=models.FileField(upload_to='miiv')
    mov_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email=models.EmailField()   #email of the uploader
    download_count=models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    #other fields follows

   @property
    def pretty_name(self):
         return "{0}.{1}".format(slugify(self.title),
                            os.path.splitext(self.mov_name.name)[1])
```

Views:

```
def document_view(request,emov_id):
    fileload=Emov.objects.get(id=emov_id)
    response=HttpResponse()
    response["Content-Disposition"]= "attachment; filename={0}".format(fileload.pretty_name)
    response['X-Accel-Redirect']="/protected/{0}".format(fileload.mov_name.name)
    return response
```

Nginx

```
  location /protected/ {
        internal;
        root /C:/Python27/Scripts/env/Scripts/digi/media/miiv/;

}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do it like this:

```
fileload = Emov.objects.get(id=emov_id)
filename = fileload.mov_file.name.split('/')[-1]
response = HttpResponse(fileload.mov_file, content_type='text/plain') # your content type
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % filename

return response
```

See:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#telling-the-browser-to-treat-the-response-as-a-file-attachment

Hope it helps.

**EDIT**:
`FileField.url` attribute you should be able to pass a path to your files (like `/protected/`). https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#filefield-and-fieldfile

Comment: thanks for the reply, what if the attachment is an application or in other format. Will 'response = HttpResponse(fileload.mov_file, content_type='text/plain')' work?

Comment: I think sometimes it could but its wise to use a proper one. Check: http://webdesign.about.com/od/multimedia/a/mime-types-by-content-type.htm

Comment: After making the changes, I was able to download the file, which is a zip file (468kb) size, I tried downloading a pdf file (1.80mb) my browser crashed and my pc hangs. Could this be due to content type? How can I determine the actual content type of a file, since I don't know the type of file users will be uploading.

Comment: Using Django Development Web Server? Mine was crashing too, it's just too much for that server. Serve those files straight from Nginx and all will be fine :D

Comment: with the view you wrote, how can I serve it with Nginx since X-Accel-Redirect is not in the view.? :)

Comment: Heh... true. My mistake. Django Gunicorn is what you need for production. Now I remembered I had problems like that making an AjaxUpload with django. Got Gunicorn for production and all is fine (uploading files bigger than 500MB).

Comment: cool. please any tutorial on how to use that for downloading files?

Comment: can you please take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20172103/send-mail-per-request-in-django